# Probleme with flutter launcher icons

Tags: flutter, dependencies

I need help for the dependencies flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.7.0,
I'm looking to insert an icon to my application from an image in.png

With an old program, the command runs perfectly.
I changed folders, created a new Flutter project, but nothing works.
I also made a clean flutter, without success

I performed flutter doctor -v and everything is fine.

Excuse me if the format is not perfect, this is my first question I'm asking here

Thank you in advance for your help

file:///E:/NexToYou/Google/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_launcher_icons-0.7.0/lib/android.dart:207:45: Error: Getter not found: 'AVERAGE'.
    newFile = copyResize(image, e.size, -1, AVERAGE);
                                            ^^^^^^^

file:///E:/NexToYou/Google/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_launcher_icons-0.7.0/lib/android.dart:207:25: Error: Too many positional arguments: 1 allowed, but 4 found.
Try removing the extra positional arguments.
    newFile = copyResize(image, e.size, -1, AVERAGE);
                        ^

file:///E:/NexToYou/Google/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image-2.1.0/lib/src/transform/copy_resize.dart:14:7: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
Image copyResize(Image src, {int width, int height,
      ^^^^^^^^^^

file:///E:/NexToYou/Google/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_launcher_icons-0.7.0/lib/android.dart:209:45: Error: Getter not found: 'LINEAR'.
    newFile = copyResize(image, e.size, -1, LINEAR);
                                            ^^^^^^

file:///E:/NexToYou/Google/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_launcher_icons-0.7.0/lib/android.dart:209:25: Error: Too many positional arguments: 1 allowed, but 4 found.
Try removing the extra positional arguments.
    newFile = copyResize(image, e.size, -1, LINEAR);
                        ^

file:///E:/NexToYou/Google/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image-2.1.0/lib/src/transform/copy_resize.dart:14:7: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
Image copyResize(Image src, {int width, int height,
      ^^^^^^^^^^

file:///E:/NexToYou/Google/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_launcher_icons-0.7.0/lib/android.dart:223:63: Error: Getter not found: 'AVERAGE'.
    newFile = copyResize(image, template.size, template.size, AVERAGE);
                                                              ^^^^^^^

file:///E:/NexToYou/Google/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_launcher_icons-0.7.0/lib/android.dart:223:25: Error: Too many positional arguments: 1 allowed, but 4 found.
Try removing the extra positional arguments.
    newFile = copyResize(image, template.size, template.size, AVERAGE);
                        ^

file:///E:/NexToYou/Google/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image-2.1.0/lib/src/transform/copy_resize.dart:14:7: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
Image copyResize(Image src, {int width, int height,
      ^^^^^^^^^^

file:///E:/NexToYou/Google/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_launcher_icons-0.7.0/lib/android.dart:226:63: Error: Getter not found: 'LINEAR'.
    newFile = copyResize(image, template.size, template.size, LINEAR);
                                                              ^^^^^^

pub finished with exit code 1[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkpog.png**)

[strong text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xgR4.png)**

Comment: What do you mean by "With an old program"?

Comment: By "old program" I mean with a program that is one or two weeks old

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It resolves in

```
flutter_launcher_icons: "0.7.3"
```

Answer (score 5):

Add these two lines to your pubspec.yaml

```
dependency_overrides:
  image: 2.0.7
```

It seems flutter_launcher_icons is not compatible with the latest version image 2.1.0. Lower version of image works. [issue#102](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_launcher_icons/issues/102)

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer and sorry for the delay.
I tried your method by adding the 2 lines but unfortunately it doesn't work. The same error is always displayed. I tried to add it in the dependencies just below flutter_launcher_icons but it didn't change anything. I had to change the image version from 2.0.7 to 2.1.1 otherwise the flutter packages get command does not work.

Comment: Do you have any indent before "dependency_overrides: "? It supposed to be at the same level as "dependencies: "(not under it)

Comment: It doesn't work, I tried in different ways:
I tried to put image in the dependencies directly, it doesn't work.
I tried to put the dependencies_overrides in the dependencies, and also underneath, it doesn't work.
And I tried adding a dash but nothing either.

I tried to write it like that too in the dependencies_overrides: image:">=2.1.3"

Answer (score 0):

In Jun 2021, I fixed it by upgrading to   `flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.9.0"`. Happy coding!
I created a post with more details about this. https://betterprogramming.pub/2-ways-to-add-app-launcher-icons-in-flutter-e9fce30bc177